# magento 2.3 update product keep websiteIds intact

Tags: magento2, multistore

Have following code:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory */
$productCollection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $_product */
foreach($productCollection as $_product) {
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository */
$product = $productRepository->get($_product->getSku(), true);
// if(in_array(2, $product->getWebsiteIds())):
$metaDescription = "custom string based on websiteId";
$product->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);

try {
    $productRepository->save($product);
    echo "saved product ".$product->getName().PHP_EOL;
} catch (\Exception $e){
    echo "couldn't save product ".$product->getName().PHP_EOL;
}
```

in console i see only messages that products were saved, but when i lookup product in backend Meta description is empty.

any other way to save product so that websiteIds will be intact ?

since if use objectmanager to load product

```
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1234);
print_r($product->getWebsitesIds());
```

i always get default website 1 meaning that i can't check if product is in another website.

Comment: Now really confused:
if i add to the first part of my code : echo $product->getMetaDescription(); i do see my custom string there. but in backend or frontend i still see empty string / default value.

Does it mean that value is saved for another store/website ?

Answer (score 0):

wel it was indeed store problem. not sure why it was always loaded store 1. not 0 the default storeview but 1.

so solved problem by specifying store:

```
/** @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager */
$storeManager->setCurrentStore(0);
```